# How to get an ArrayList from a generic HashMap with a generic condition

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Let's suppose I have:

- an Hashmap_A, made of object_A (then for example in order to push a new object inside the HashMap I use 'myHashmap_A.put( KEY_integer,  myObject_A)'  ); object_A is an istance of a class A, having an attribute Attribute_A1 and an Attribute_A2.
- an Hashmap_B, made of object_B ; object_B is an istance of a class B, having an attribute Attribute_B1 and an Attribute_B2.
- an Hashmap_C, made of object_C ; object_C is an istance of a class C, having an attribute Attribute_C1 and an Attribute_C2.
- etc...

I'd like to have a generic method that builds an ArrayList of object_xxx where the Attribute_xxx=K, then to be used with whatever HashMap.

Something like:    myHashmap_xxx.getArrayList(nameOfAttribute_xxx, K);

Any idea?

NEW EDIT:

According to answer below by 'JB Nizet' , I should have something like:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

public static <O> List<O> getObjectWithAttributeEqualTo(Map<?, O> MyMap_Arg, Function<O, ?> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg, Object MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg) {
        return MyMap_Arg.stream().filter(o -> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg.apply(o).equals(MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It doesn't work at me because my IDE (Netbeans) cannot find method stream(); looking at documentation, stream() seems a mthod of a List, and not of a Map...

I tryied to modify it in this way (adding 'values()'), and it finally doesn't give me any error in IDE:

```
public <O> List<O> getObjectWithAttributeEqualTo(Map<?, O> MyMap_Arg, Function<O, ?> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg, Object MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg) {
    return  MyMap_Arg.values().stream().filter(o -> MY_AttributeValueExtractor_Arg.apply(o).equals(MY_AttributeValueToEqual_Arg)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Now the problem is another; let's say I have a Class called 'CAR' with a NOT STATIC method 'getColor()'. I have the object 'myHashMap', that is a map of carr, then HashMap. I want for example get the list of red cars inside my myHashMap. If I use:

```
List<Car> redCars = getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(myHashMap, Car::getColor, "red");
```

I get an error in the IDE because it says that getColor is not static (and it must not be static, I cannot change it).

If I use the other method suggested in the answer:

```
List<Car> redCars = getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(myHashMap, car -> car.getColor(), "red");
```

I don't understand what is car; is it an instance of Car? If I put 'new Car()' instead of car it doesn't work...

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify. I've read this a few times and cannot work out what you are trying to achieve. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with a generic solution?

Comment: Do you want the generic function to be a function of your map or can a function take your map in as a parameter?

Comment: Regardind the second comment, I can use both the solutions. The target is to get an arraylist from a generic HashMap.

Regarding the first comment I don't know how to explain better... What I need is to have a method that return an arraylist of objects getting as input an hashmap made by those objects. When I say generic, it is because I want to apply that method to different hashmaps (made by different objects)

Comment: `List<ObjectA> result = map.values().stream().filter(o -> o.getSomeAttribute().equals(someValue)).collect(Collector.toList());`

Comment: @JB Nizet  ; to be honest I don't understand how it should work.  The generic method doesn't know in advance which object and which attibute has to use, they are arguments of the method.... I suppose that what I need is impossible, and the problem is the name of attribute...

Comment: The line I posted is all you need to do what you want. If you want to do the same thing with ObjectC and someOtherAttribute, then use `List<ObjectC> result = map.values().stream().filter(o -> o.getSomeOtherAttribute().equals(someValue)).collect(Collector.to‌​List());`. Of course, you could extract this to a generic method taking a Function<T, A> objectToAttribute and a A attributeValue, but is it really worth it, when the whole thing can be expressed as a single, simple line of code?

Comment: @JB Nizet  I edited the question to better explain, also because I don't know how to get your code working. Can you show the corrected code please?

Comment: I posted a longer answer.

Comment: @JB Nizet I edited again the question to better explain what is my problem now. Probably it's something stupid, but I need your expert eye...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get an attribute by name in Java. Or rather, you can, but it requires to use reflection, which is almost always a bad idea: it makes the code not type-safe, slower, not refactorable.

So, instead of using an attribute *name*, what you should instead do is pass a function which allows to get an attribute value.

Suppose you have a `Map<Integer, Car>` (note the use of the interface, rather than the concrete type. And note the use of generic types. And note the respect of the Java naming conventions, making the code readable).

Suppose that Car has a property "color" (an thus a method `getColor()` returning, for example, a String). And suppose you want to extract to a list all the cars with a color equal to "red", the method body would look like that:

```
List<Car> result = map.values().stream().filter(o -> o.getColor().equals("red")).collect(Collect‌​or.to‌​List());
```

This line is so simple that I don't think you need to extract a generic method to do this with other types of objects. If you had to do the same thing with a `Map<Integer, Animal>` and the property `species`, you would simply type the above again:

```
List<Animal> result = map.values().stream().filter(o -> o.getSpecies().equals("dog")).collect(Collect‌​or.to‌​List());
```

**If** you really want to extract this simple line of code to a generic method, you need:

- a generic type for the object type (Car or Animal in the previous examples)
- a type for the function that allows getting the attribute value from the object: that would be a Function:

.

```
public <O> List<O> getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(Map<?, O> map, Function<O, ?> attributeValueExtractor, Object valueToEqual) {
    // ...
}
```

And its implementation would be

```
public <O> List<O> getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(Map<?, O> map, Function<O, ?> attributeValueExtractor, Object valueToEqual) {
    return map.stream().filter(o -> attributeValueExtractor.apply(o).equals(valueToEqual)).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
Map<Integer, Car> map = ...:
List<Car> redCars = getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(map, car -> car.getColor(), "red");
```

or, with a method reference:

```
Map<Integer, Car> map = ...:
List<Car> redCars = getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo(map, Car::getColor, "red");
```

But once again, the inline version of this method is so simple and easy to read, understand, and adapt that I wouldn't create this `getValuesWithAttributeEqualTo` in the first place.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work to me: Collect‌​or doesn't have a methos 'to‌​List()'. I used the only import I get from IDE: java.util.stream.Collector.

Comment: The class is named Collectors, not Collector.

Comment: I edited again the question to better explain what is my problem now. Probably it's something stupid, but I need your expert eye...